# Serialization of object of one class and setting properties of other class

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to understand the xml serialization/Deserialization  behavior in C#. I am working with following example code:

```
[Serializable]
public class Class1 {
    Class2 c2 = new Class2( );

    public List<double>  Arr2 {
        get { return c2.Arr1 ;}
        set { c2.Arr1 = value ;}
    } 
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Class2 C2 {
        get { return c2; }
        set { c2 = value; }
    }

    public Class1( ) {
    }
}

public class Class2 {
    private List<double> arr1;

    public List<double> Arr1 {
        get { return arr1; }
        set { arr1 = value; }
     }

     public Class2( ) {
        arr1 = (new double[ 5 ]).ToList();    
      }
}
```

Every time when I deserialize the xml file for class1, I get zeros in Arr2 instead of values from xml file. I am using following lines for deserialization:

```
public Class1 c1 = new Class1 () ;
XElement rootnode = XElement.Load( path );
c1 = rootnode.XmlDeserialize<Class1>( "Class1" );
```

Xml file:

```
<Class1>
<Arr2>
    <double>1</double>
    <double>2</double>
    <double>3</double>
    <double>4</double>
    <double>5</double>  
</Arr2>
</Class1>
```

Comment: Where is `XElement.XmlDeserialize<Class1>( "Class1" );` coming from? I can't find any documentation anywhere. I can only presume it's an extension method defined in your project. You should include it

Comment: If some one is going to down vote then please leave a comment for indication of mistake which I made. It is my humble request. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `[Serializable]` attribute to `class2`.

OK, from the comment, I can see I was wrong.

This worked for me:

```
XElement rootnode = XElement.Load( path );
var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Class1));
var c1 = (Class1)serializer.Deserialize(rootnode.CreateReader());
```

Comment: The `Serializable` attribute is used by the `BinaryFormatter` only. XMLSerializer does not care about it.

Comment: I stand corrected. Does that mean that the `Serializable` attribute on `Class1` in the example code is unnecessary?